# How to get Reference Fields in embedded block's using Gatsby and Contentful's Rich Text fields

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful

I have a rich text editor field that accepts an embedded block where the content type contains a reference link to another content type.

Like this:

```
content (rich text field)
  - group (embedded block)
    - group-items (reference field)
      - item 1 (referenced content)
      - item 2 (referenced content)
```

How can I get the `referenced content` items using `@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer`?

I currently have this:

```
import { MARKS, BLOCKS } from '@contentful/rich-text-types';
import { documentToReactComponents } from '@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer';

const options = {
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY]: (node) => {
      console.log(node);
      return true;
    }
  },
  renderText: text => text.replace('!', '?'),
};
```

Which gives me a bunch of id's but not of the field data for the entries which is what I really want.

```
content: []
data:
target: {sys: {…}}
__proto__: Object
nodeType: "embedded-entry-block"

content: []
data:
target:
sys: {id: "c13cBu2W6nOkQMx6bsvqCE5", type: "Link", linkType: "Entry"}
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
nodeType: "embedded-entry-block"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There where 2 problems I was running into here.

Firstly coccasionally Gatsby's cache will cause issues retriving new data from contentful and as such you may only get `sys` not `fields`. Which is what was happening to me.

Just delete `.cache` and rerun `yarn run dev` and it should be good.

Secondly to get multiple contentTypes with enter blocks this can be achieved by looking for the Entry blocks `sys.id`. This way you can create different components to handle various content types.

```
[BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY]: (node) => {
      const fields = node.data.target.fields;

      switch (node.data.target.sys.contentType.sys.id) {
        case 'group-item':
          return <div>
            <GroupItem name={fields.name['en-US']} />
          </div>
        default:
           return <div>Fallback Element</div>
}
```

Comment: Furthermore, remember that you have to fetch `contentful_id` inside the references in the GraphQL query, otherwise, all the other fields won't get populated